# Getting data from Firestore with a specific document id

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data that is stored in firebase with a specific document, from repository:

```
suspend fun getUserFromFirestore(id: String): User? {
    val data = db.collection("users").document(id)
        .get()
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.d("Repository", "exception:" + it.message.toString())
        }
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            Log.d("Repository", "data:" + document.data.toString())
        }
        .await()

    return data.toObject<User>()
}
```

viewmodel:

```
fun getDataFromFirestore(id:String): User? {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            data = firestoreRepo.getUserFromFirestore(id)
        }
         return data
    }
```

And from screen I pass the id for every item:

```
LazyColumn {
            items(state.matches) {
                MatchItem(
                    it,
                    vm,
                    it.id.toString()
                )
            }
```

Which I receive from the item composable:

```
@Composable
fun MatchItem(
    match: Match,
    vm: HomeViewModel,
    id:String
) {
     
    val data = vm.getDataFromFirestore(id)

    val team1 = data?.team1
    val team2  = data?.team2
    val chosen = data?.chosen

    Log.d("HomeScreen", data?.toString())
}
```

But then what I receive is data that is constantly changing (and the same thing with the data on the screen):

> 2022-08-08 16:08:36.898 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=2,
> team2=0, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:36.915 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=0, team2=2, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:37.159 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=2, team2=0, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:37.239 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=0, team2=2, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:37.491 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=2, team2=0, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:37.496 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=2, team2=0, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:37.547 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=0, team2=2, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:37.551 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=0, team2=2, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:37.757 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=0, team2=2, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:37.760 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=0, team2=2, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:37.762 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=2, team2=0, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:37.764 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=2, team2=0, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:37.978 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=2, team2=0, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:38.046 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=0, team2=2, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:38.419 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=0, team2=2, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:38.423 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=2, team2=0, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:39.067 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=2, team2=0, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:39.072 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=0, team2=2, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:39.328 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=2, team2=0, chosen=true}
> 2022-08-08 16:08:39.337 28603-28603/? D/HomeScreen: data:{team1=0, team2=2, chosen=true}
> .......................

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "constantly changing"? I only see a `get()` call. Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that. The log is just for one document id. And as you can see in each case the number is changing either to 2 or 0. In each case either team1 is equal to 0 or 2 and the same with team2